# How to get parent entity property in child entity with foreign key relation in code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have following two entities Doctor(parent) and DoctorPayment(child)

1. one possible way is to take Doctor object in DoctorPayment entity and get through Doctor.Name
2. But I only need DoctorName not whole object in DoctorPayment that should be mapped by DoctorId

I have mentioned just few properties of Doctor entity but it have around 50 properties so I don't want to take Doctor object in DoctorPayment

```
public class Doctor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }

    public class DoctorPayment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int DoctorId { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }      // a possible way to take Doctor object
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Currently not Possible with Entity Framework.EF does Support Object Mapping Only.You can't Map Single Column using EF.

Only Posssible way is to Get Maping for Whole object i.e Doctor and then you can use EF select to get Name only
i.e

```
var DoctorName=DoctorPayment.Doctor.Name
```

Answer (score 3):

To be completely honest, my hunch is that you are probably prematurely optimizing. Unless you have already profiled your software and established that fetching just one instead of all columns is performance-critical, I would not bother to optimize it yet.

However, to answer your question: You can make EF retrieve single columns like this:

```
var name=dbContext.Doctors.Where(d=>d.ID==DoctorId).Select(d=>d.Name)
```

And of course you can also encapsulate this in a read-only property in the DoctorPayment class if you often need to access this.

Note that the disadvantage of this approach is that you are always fetching the Name from DB, even if the Doctor entity might already be prefetched through lazy loading by a previous query.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.DoctorPayment.Include(x=>x.Doctor).Where(...).Select(x=>new{docName=x.Doctor.Name,.....})
```

it will generate a sql like

```
select doctor.name,.... from doctorpayment inner join doctor on ... where ...
```

Comment: -1: The Include statement is not required here. Include is only necessary if you want to prefetch additional referenced entitites which would usually be lazy-loaded.